# How can I fix wrong encoding in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, encoding

I have a table where from what I found out has Windows 1252 encoding and I need an SQL function which converts it to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

I have text like this:

Str. IGNÃCZ RÃ“ZSA 11

Str. Sebesului, nr. 116 ï¿½ Constructia C2

How can I fix it ? There is any SQL which allows converting the encoding ?

Comment: Nope, once the data has been corrupted it has been corrupted. You'll need to get the original source and reinsert it correctly.

Comment: Though your opening statement doesn't make much sense. `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` uses the code page `1252`: `SELECT COLLATIONPROPERTY('SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI', 'CodePage');`. I don't think that source data *was* using the Windows 1252 code page.

Comment: This looks like mojibake generated by incorrectly decoded UTF-8. The very first thing you should do is verify how this is getting into the database and fix it, otherwise changing the values now isn't going to do you any good if new data is going to keep arriving corrupted. The second thing you should do is verify your columns have types and collations that allow for all the possible characters; the default Latin-1 collations don't contain everything and `N[VAR]CHAR`s are almost always a better idea if you plan on storing anything beyond ASCII.